# Java Android - Issue with pulling a variable from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

So I am trying to pull an integer called "totalWater" from my SQLite database but when I try to pull it and then add it to another number, it shows that the number that I pulled from the database is zero. I'm not sure if I am pulling wrong, or if I am even storing the value into the database wrong.

here is my code dealing with pulling and pushing with the database:

```
//pull data
data = new Database(SetupTimerPC1.this);
data.open();
totalWater = data.getWaterAmt();            
data.close();

//add new data to old
totalWater+=waterAmt;

//push data
data.open();
data.waterAmountEntry(totalWater);
data.close();
```

here is the function in the database dealing with waterAmt:

```
public int getWaterAmt() 
{
    int waterAmount = 0;

    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK, KEY_WATER,
    KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE, KEY_SHOVELEXP,
    KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        iWaterAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WATER);
        waterAmount = c.getInt(iWaterAmount);
        return waterAmount;
    }//end if        return 0;
}//end getWaterAmt function
```

and here is my waterAmountEntry function to enter the amount of water into the database:

```
public long waterAmountEntry(int waterAmt)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_WATER, waterAmt);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}//end waterAmountEntry function
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `getWaterAmt` function returns the water value from some random row in the table. Is that what you want?

Comment: There should only be one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a for loop that started at c.moveToFirst() with a condition of !c.isafterlast() and increment by c.movetonext() inside of my if statement checking if the cursor was null allowed me to fix the issue:

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
{
    iWaterAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WATER);
    waterAmount = c.getInt(iWaterAmount);
}//end for
c.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {...}
```

then you will know whether you have a record stored or not.

Comment: I got the same numbers as before when doing this so I am assuming I am not storing correctly. No idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

data.createEntry(0, 0, totalWater, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

&

String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK, KEY_WATER,
    KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE, KEY_SHOVELEXP,
    KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP};

columns are not match

Comment: They are not supposed to match in that way...createEntry is a function that has parameters in a particular order which this matched. I have changed the format anyways so it does not matter.